# why define new object in for loop is not error in redefine

Tags: java

```
for(int i=1; i<=6; i++){
    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

It is my java code, very simple, but if outside the for loop, if I define a twice, it will report an error. But Why in a loop it will not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Difference lies with the scope**

In first case `List<Integer> a` is referenced till the end of the `main method`, so compiler will compalin , if we have two variable of the same name in the same scope.

For second case, every time the loop executes, `List<Integer> a` for the last iteration is no longer referenced and hence we can declare again.

Answer (score 0):

In a loop the declared variable is only till the loop,once the loop iterates the previously declared variable no longer exists.But, its not the case once you are out of the loop and hence the error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a variable if there is an existing in the current variable scope.

In your case, it is unreferenced every time in the end of iteration:

```
for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
{
   List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // variable a is declared

   // ...

   // end of iteration. variable a is unreferenced
}
```

It is an other variable scope. 
It is the same as if you had a function.
It is not a declaring.
*Such a poor explanation. I hope I will not confuse you even more*

```
public void Func()
{
   List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
   // do something
}

for (int i=1; i<=6; i++)
{
    Func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**in the loop**
`List<Integer> a` will be destroyed when `i++`.

**outside the loop**
`List<Integer> a` won't be destroyed when `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare two variables having same name (although they have different type) to exist in the same scope. Consider if it was possible then how would the java compiler determine which one you meant:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Error: Duplicate variable a
a.clear() // cannot determine which 'a' you meant
```

Now in `for` loop compiler will see only one variable `a` is declared and its fine for him! So no compiler error.

But when the loop iterates, every time a `List a` is created and the previous `a` became garbage. We are lucky as JAVA has Garbage Collector which collect the garbage of *orphan* `List a`.

Don't `new` local variable `a` into the `for` loop, it is nothing but memory leak.